# Properly preventing orientation change in Flex Mobile app

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, air, orientation

Is anyone able to actually make it work properly in Flex SDK 4.6?

Here's a short snippet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        addedToStage="onAddedToStage(event)"
        title="Title">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[  
            private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void { 
                if (stage.autoOrients) {
                    stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChanging, false, 0, true);
                }
            }

            private function orientationChanging(event:StageOrientationEvent):void {
                if (event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.DEFAULT || event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                }     
            } 
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to support Landscape mode in both orientations, so if user turns the device 180 degress, the screen should also rotate. But there should be no action at all, when user rotates the device to one of portrait orientations. Instead, I'm seeing width changes to navigator action bar and sometimes content in portrait orientations, so apparently preventing the event is not enough.  I'm using the "official" way Adobe suggests, but the problem is that it's not working very well. Granted, the stage does not change, but it seems that there's something firing in navigator anyway, since you can see the action bar width changing.

I had some success with explicitly setting layoutbounds to fixed width in handler method - this prevents changing the actionbar width, but it's only a temporary solution - if the view is a subject to a transition, or some other redraw - it will again render with bad sizes. As if there was something below that was telling it that it's in portrait mode, even though I'm trying to prevent it.

Before you detonate with some silly ideas like "autoOrient = false", don't. It's clearly not a solution for this problem. Obviously it's a bug with Flex SDK - did anyone find a way to fix it or a stable workaround?

EDIT: apparently others bumped into similar issue:
- http://forums.adobe.com/message/3969531 (the main topic is about something else, but read magic robots's comment)
- http://forums.adobe.com/message/4130972

Comment: That's strange because that's exactly what I use in my application and it works extremely well. What SDK version are you using? EDIT : Okay sorry, just realized it was on the first line of you question! That's the version I use so I don't have any idea at all. Have you tried doing it in your application class (I don't see why this would change anything but that's the only thing that comes to my mind)

Comment: Are you sure? Can you create new flex mobile project, use my code in view, compile and see (it can be seen even in debugger, you don't have to put it on device). Can you paste relevant fragments from your code? My example is extremely simple, no additional code, no skinning, nothing, yet it clearly fails to work properly - so I find it hard to believe it works for you?

Comment: Yep, just replaced my code with yours and it works on an iPad. I don't monitor my action bar width though but it stays exactly where it is. I'm adding the listener directly on the addedToStage of my ViewNavigatorApplication

Comment: I've tried it also in main application file - still not working. It's blatantly visible in debugger emulator, when you rotate it using debugger menu - the stage does not change, yet the action bar changes its width as if it was in portrait mode. My application starts in aspectRatio=landscape mode (defined in xml). Do you use FB 4.6 with SDK 4.6? Windows or Mac OS?

Comment: Ok, I've done some tests and yeah, the action bar size does change in the emulator and (sometimes ?) on the device. I don't have any idea on this and I unfortunetely don't have time to investigate more. Sorry :( FYI : FB and Flex 4.6 on Windows (I do have a prerelease version of FB but that shouldn't change anything)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right one, did I do something wrong in the end, but after a lot of struggle, I've found this one to be stable solution:

```
private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void { 
    if (stage.autoOrients) {
        stage.removeEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChanging);
        stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChanging, false, 100, true);
    }
}      

private function orientationChanging(event:StageOrientationEvent):void {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.DEFAULT || event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }   
}
```

First thing to note is that addedToStage fires few times (2-3) in mobile application. I don't know why, there's no addChild in my code, obviously. Maybe the AIR runtime does something else. So, to avoid adding unnecessary amount of handlers, the common technique is to remove handler first - it won't do anything, if such handler is not yet registered, but if there is, it will remove it, which will maintain the handler count on 1.

Second thing is the priority of the event - it won't work on 0, it has to be set on something big, to launch before stuff in AIR runtime.

Last thing - event.stopImmediatePropagation() - now, that we're the first to handle the event, we cant prevent this event to be sent further up in this particular scenario.

This together makes the orientation preventing working perfectly - for me the landscape and the reversed landscape (rotated_left, rotated_right) were working and transitioning, while portrait modes did not affect the view at all.

Now, there's danger here - you might want to remove the listener upon leaving the view (on transition animation end, view deactivate or something), because stopImmediatePropagation will prevent the event to be handled in other parts of your application.

I hope Adobe (or Apache now, actually) will take a closer look at this problem and trace my solution.

**EDIT**

There remaisn a last issue with this solution, which is if application starts while device is in DEFAULT or UPSIDE_DOWN orientation, in this case application will be in portrait mode.

To fix this, a solution is to change Aspect Ratio within addedToStage handler:

```
   if(Stage.supportsOrientationChange) {
         stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

Comment: For further investigation, from what I've gathered, this is somewhat related to stage.width and height - when I was trying to manipulate them in orientationChanging, I was able to maintain proper behaviour sometimes. For sure, even though the event is prevented, the FlexGlobals.topApplication.aspectRatio changes to portrait, though it shouldn't.

Comment: Solution works perfectly except for startup. I you start with device in DEFAULT or UPSIDE_DOWN then application will be in portrait mode

Comment: thank you for solution! you save my time...why adobe's developers still ignoring such important bugs and issues :( no idea..

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same problem you had. I think I finally figured out the solution. Heres what I did:

```
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
...blahblahblah...
width="1024"/>

protected function tabbedviewnavigatorapplication2_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
    stage.autoOrients=true;
    preventOrient();
} 

private function preventOrient():void { 
    if (stage.autoOrients) {
        stage.removeEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChanging);
    stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChanging, false, 100, true);
    }
}

private function orientationChanging(event:StageOrientationEvent):void {
    if(event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.DEFAULT || event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN || event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.UNKNOWN) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

Worth noting is that in the application complete handler I set stage.autoOrients to true because in the app.xml file I have it set to false, due to having a splash screen and not wanting users to re-orient the screen during that time. Really the only thing I did different is account for the StageOrientation.UNKNOWN and prevent whatever that would do, set the width to 1024(for the iPad screen, might be different for other tablet devices) in the main mxml file, and removed the stopimmediatepropagation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, frankly, you did not *figured out* the solution, you just copied mine. That's fine, but please don't distort the reality :)

Comment: Changing stage.autoOrients during runtime can still yield some weird results from time to time (not so long ago it was read-only property) and I would not recommend doing that (I just modify preloader to prevent rotation). Also I've been experimenting with setting the stage width/height manually, as mentioned before, but this is also not 100% right all the time and actually quite inflexible solution. In my tests, I've never encountered StageOrientation.UNKNOWN, that's why it's not there in my example.