# Handle orientation's change when device's auto rotate's feature is disabled in Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, screen-orientation, device-orientation

"StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE" event does not fire (dispatch) when the Auto Rotate feature of the device is disabled.

I'm developing a game that only must work on PORTRAIT mode. I speculate many users unchecked this option display settings.

How can I detect screen rotation regardless of device setting. Should I use accelerometer for this purpose or there is a better way?

[image: Auto-rotate screen" option in Display settings of Google Nexus]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your game must always work in PORTRAIT mode; then you don't have to worry about device orientation changes.  What you want to do is make sure your game always launches in portrait mode despite what the device settings are.

In the Application Descriptor file; set these values:

```
<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
```

The application descriptor file is the "*MainApplication*-app.xml' file that Flash Builder will create as you create your main application.

In documentation theory those changes should do it; but if memory serves me I had problems in some versions of Android, where the app launched in the wrong orientation and would not change.

So, inside my application I added applicationComplete and activate handlers on my main application file and used those methods to specify the aspect ratio of the game.  Something like this:

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
applicationComplete="viewnavigatorapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)"
activate="viewnavigatorapplication1_activateHandler(event)"> 
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    protected function viewnavigatorapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
      this.stage.setAspectRatio( StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT);
    }

    protected function viewnavigatorapplication1_activateHandler(event:Event):void{
      if(this.stage){
        this.stage.setAspectRatio( StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT );
      }
}

]]></fx:Script>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

I have no memory of testing this specific use case on iOS Devices; so it is possible I only had the problem on Android.  Or it is possible I did the Android code first and that is why I never had a problem on iOS.

Comment: Awesome! This works very well on Android device. I have not tested it on iOS yet. By "Portrait" I actually means "Landscape". Is there a way to change the stage aspect ratio accordingly in ROTATERIGHT and ROTATELEFT mode?

Comment: In another word: Is it possible to enable autoOrient only for landscape? Considering that "Auto-rotate screen" option might be unchecked in user's device.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear what you want to do that this doesn't already cover.  To force your app always into landscape mode; you can switch the aspectRatio to landscape wherever I have portrait specified.

Comment: I changed it to LANDSCAPE and it work find except one small but important detail. If user flip device 180 degree app is upside down. In other want I want my app to re Orient but only in landscape mode.

Comment: This blog post says LANDSCAPE means both LANSCAPE_LEFT & LANDSCAPE_RIGHT. But in my case it's just LANDSCAPE_RIGHT. I want my app to reorient in both left and right landscape orientation: http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/05/22/stage-aspectratio-enhancements/

Comment: I understand the problem now.  I don't think I accommodate for the "Flip device around" scenario; I honestly never tested.  I don't anticipate folks will flip the device around while using my app.  I would assume that setting auto-orient to false in the descriptor would prevent the app rotate events from dispatching.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have used this method, I cannot take credit for it but please see: [Please see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249226/how-can-i-properly-control-stage-orientation-on-android-with-air-mobile)

Remember if you are developing for iOS, you CANNOT LOCK Device Orientation. You HAVE to add event listeners to handle orientation changes for iOS. The very first app I did got rejected for trying to lock orientation.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But the solution described in the post does NOT work when "Auto-rotate screen" is unchecked in Display setting, as I explained in my question. Event.RESIZE nor StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE fired when the device get rotated!