# How to enable orientation change for some views in Flex Mobile?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have some views in my mobile app (for both ios and android) whose orientation was fixed to `PORTRAIT` using `<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio><autoOrients>false</autoOrients>` in the settings xml file.

Now I have added another view which plays video from Youtube and it should be able to play videos, both in `LANDSCAPE` & `PORTRAIT` orientation. So I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900849/properly-preventing-orientation-change-in-flex-mobile-app) which provides a solution to restrict only 1 orientation (globally for all views), but how can I re-enable orientation change only for one view?

**Note**: I am using Flash Builder 4.6 with actionscript 3 and [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference)

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio><autoOrients>false</autoOrients>` from XML, **as it will generalize it for the whole application.**

Do it separately for each and every view. Since for first view you need a **PORTRAIT**, do it like this.(*Taken from Adobe Docs*)

```
stage.addEventListener( StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, onOrientationChanging ); 

function onOrientationChanging( event:StageOrientationEvent ):void {
    // If the stage is about to move to an orientation we don't support, lets prevent it
    // from changing to that stage orientation.
    if(event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT || event.afterOrientation==StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT ) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

For the second view, do not define any stage orientation listeners, as you need both **PORTRAIT** and **LANDSCAPE**.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. There are many views so I asked is there a way  **globally for all views** to restrict it & enable only for 1 view? As I do not want to add code in all the views which should have restricted orientation.

Comment: Why don't you just define this in a seperate AS and call it whichever view you want. Since the XML part globalizes what you put in there.

Comment: I am looking for a way where I do not need to add **any code** on the views which should be orientation restricted (since I have many views) but add to only video playback view to enable orientation. If that is not possible i'll have to go with this solution :)

Comment: I guess there is no turnaround, however i suggest you open a bounty on this question(if you are really serious about the solution), such that some experts will find a way out.

Comment: any idea what should I use for resetting yt player's size on orientation change? `this.stage.stageWidth` or `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width` or `this.stage.width` or any other?